# Aptana Studio 3.4.1 'Show Preview Editor' not working

Tags: html, aptana3

I've just installed Aptana Studio 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have create a sample HTML5 page from the boiler plate provided. when I try to preview it in the Preview Editor it just shows the HTML. [image: Aptana Screenshot]
According to this post. This problem should have been resolved in the new release. Has this been resolved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be corrected in version 3.4.2